# chr to date class in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing dates as **characters**,`dd.mm.yyyy` format. want to convert those in date class, format `yyyy-m-d`. `as.date()` is not working returning error, **do not know how to convert 'dates' to class “Date”**

```
dates <- data.frame(cbind(c("5.1.2015", "6.1.2014", "17.2.2014", "28.10.2014")))
colnames(dates) <- c("dates")
as.Date(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

new_format_dates <- cbind(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", dates[1:nrow(dates),1]))
as.Date(new_format_dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

So I tried to replace the `.` and reformat those dates under `new_format_dates`, returning result like `[1] NA NA NA NA`

Comment: a. Never, never do `data.frame(cbind(...))`. b. You need to set your format correctly, and treat your data as strings, not a factor (which it will be unless you set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`): `as.Date(as.character(dates$dates), format = "%d.%m.%Y")`

Comment: @alistaire - `as.character()` doesn't seem to matter here - `as.Date(dates$dates, format = "%d.%m.%Y")` works fine.

Comment: Curious...`as.Date` is a machete of a function. I've passed it some horrific strings, and it still finds a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, make your data.frames properly; don't use `cbind` in `data.frame`. Next, set the `format` argument of `as.Date` to the format you've got, including separators. If you don't know the symbol you need, check out `?strptime`.

```
dates <- data.frame(dates = c("5.1.2015", "6.1.2014", "17.2.2014", "28.10.2014"))
dates$dates_new <- as.Date(dates$dates, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
dates
#        dates  dates_new
# 1   5.1.2015 2015-01-05
# 2   6.1.2014 2014-01-06
# 3  17.2.2014 2014-02-17
# 4 28.10.2014 2014-10-28
```

Comment: That's really wonderful. I understand my mistakes previously and big thanks for the tip, `cbind`, I will keep in mind that.

Answer (score 1):

```
dates <- data.frame(cbind(c("5.1.2015", "6.1.2014", "17.2.2014", "28.10.2014")))
colnames(dates) <- c("dates")

dates$new_Dates <- gsub("[.]","-",dates$dates) 
dates$dates <- NULL
dates_new <- as.Date(dates$new_Dates, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

dates_new <- data.frame(dates_new)
print(dates_new)
```

Comment: Not any better. I'll just post so you can see.

Comment: Good post.  Plus one